# Webworker OffscreenCanvas draw regular image

Tags: javascript, canvas, web-worker

Webworkers can fetch regular images through `XMLHttpRequest`, right? How can the workers then draw these images to OffscreenCanvas? Probably want to use `XMLHttp.responseType = 'blob'`?

Another way would be to set the `src` of an image element and then transfer the element to worker, but my workers always reject such images.

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The [ImageBitmap API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/createImageBitmap) is here for this purpose (among others).

*Note: this demo will currently run only on Chrome...*

```js
const offcanvas = canvas.transferControlToOffscreen();
const worker = new Worker(getWorkerURL());
worker.onmessage = e => console.log(e.data);
worker.postMessage(offcanvas, [offcanvas]);


function getWorkerURL() {
  return URL.createObjectURL(
    new Blob([
      worker_script.textContent
    ])
  );
}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" height="450"></canvas>

<script id="worker_script" type="ws">
onmessage = async (evt) => {
  try {
    const canvas = evt.data;
    const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
    if(!ctx) {
      postMessage('unsupported browser');
      return;
    }
    const imgblob = await fetch('https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/5/55/John_William_Waterhouse_A_Mermaid.jpg')
      .then(r => r.blob());
    const img = await createImageBitmap(imgblob);
    ctx.drawImage(img, 0,0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
 }
 catch(e) {
  postMessage('unsupported browser');
  throw e;
  }
};
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks. I think you missed the `return` before `r.blob()`. Aside of that, i noticed a huge memory consumption after several hundreds of iterations (even with only one image). If i exclude the canvas, then the memory atleast enfrees itself automatically. Could you suggest how to get over that memory issue with canvas?

Comment: No, arrow function that consist of only one statement don't need a `return`. And for your memory issue, I'm not sure what you mean... Can you setup an [MCVE]? But note that it's quite normal it takes memory (the pixels have to be stored somewhere), but it should free itself after the GC came in (which may be never if you have enough mem' available).

Comment: [An iteration of 120 times.](https://jsfiddle.net/07xfejt1/) If we comment out the `drawImage`, then RAM will go back to normal. Thats sad, because it gives no advantage to use workers with multiple `OffscreenCanvas`. Even if i pass offscreen to worker, ram stays the same. ([A quick example without workers](https://jsfiddle.net/4tvnouc2/))

Comment: @ituy Of course that takes memory, you are initializing 120 2000x2000px canvases! That's roughly 4*4*8*2000*2000, 5MB per canvas raw image data, **and** you create a new ImageBitmap per iteration. Web Workers only allow to run scripts in an other CPU thread, but they're not magic and still have to allocate memory. Your second fiddle uses 300x150px canvases (500KB per canvas), and the browser will use the same bitmap every time (because of cache). A more fair version of the first fiddle would be https://jsfiddle.net/rza8f6nv/ but it will still consume memory obviously.